# Eclipse Indigo generating HTML5 warnings in HTML4 snippets

Tags: eclipse, doctype, html4

I work for a company who's primary clients still use Internet Explorer 7 (NHS etc).

In our code we generate snippets of HTML in various places and Eclipse is generating lots of warnings relating to markup that is obsolete in HTML5.

I know that setting a valid doctype of HTML4 fixes the problem on flat html files but as we build the code over several PHP files we can't set a doctype in the snippets.

Is there a way to change the 'default' doctype to HTML4 globally or by project as I do not want to turn off the warnings as that may cause me to miss actual issues.

Comment: perhaps this will solve the problem -> http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/219788/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drove me nuts too until I found the answer...

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/219788/

Steps:

1. Select an HTML file in the PHP Explorer. If there are no HTML files, create a new one.
2. Right-click > Properties > Web Content Settings.
3. Choose *preferred doctype* in the *Document type* list.
4. Click OK and exit Eclipse.
5. Open `{your_workspace}/{your_project}/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.html.core.prefs` with a text editor.
6. Replace `document-type/{your_file_name}=...` by `document-type/<project>=...` (do not modify `<project>`, paste it as-is)
7. Start Eclipse.